# Abstract class with inheritance classes and functions writing into separate vectors c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, virtual, abstract

Card game; I'm using abstract class for the "hands" which hold cards. The "hands" need to be slightly different but they share majority of the functions. So there is a Hand and a MasterHand which will inherit from the Hand and have an additional function. Everything goes through the deck which deals cards. My aim is to formulate the function within the Hand class in a way which allows writing into handV of the instance of the Abstract class that is called- regardless of it being Hand of MasterHand.. I've tried different methods but couldn't make any of them work.

```
class AbstractClass
{
    virtual ~AbstractClass(){}        
    virtual void getCard(Card::card)=0 ;

};

class Hand:public AbstractClass
 {
 public: 
    vector<Card::card> handV;
    virtual void getCard(Card::card k) override
    {
        writeIntoVector(k);
    }
    void writeIntoArray(Card::card g)
    {
        handV.push_back(g);
    }
};
class HandMaster:public Hand
{
    public: 
    vector<Card::card> handV;
// now here I would like to use the functions from Hand, but make them write into HandMaster.handV rather than Hand.handV
};

class Deck
{
    void passCard(AbstractBase &x)
    {
        x.getCard(deck.back());
    }
};

int main
{
    AbstractBase* k=&h;
    Hand* p = static_cast<Hand*>(k);  // so I was trying to do it via casting in different convoluted ways but failed
    MasterHand h2;
    AbstractBase* m=&h2;
    d.passCard(*k); // here I'd like the card to be passed to Hand.handV
    d.passCard(*m); // here I'd like the card to be passed to MasterHand.handV
}
```

Comment: you are missing class specifier before Hand and HandMaster, also the destructor in AbstractClass should be declared as virtual as well, so the derived class is destroyed. One more thing, if this is a pure abstract class then set both virtual functions in the Abstract class equal to zero like virtual void getCard(Card::card) =0;

Comment: that's all true, it's not the actual code, just snippets brought together, got the destructor in the abstract class and the virtual void is pure virtual- I will edit now to clarify, but it doesn't solve my issue.. thanks

Comment: declare all hand methods virtual and override the functionality to use the handmaster vector

Comment: not sure how to do that! I've tried quite a bit and without copying and pasting the functionality I get segmentation failures

Comment: i will write a solution, give me one sec

Comment: did this fix your problem? If so could you mark as answerd, if not explain so I can help further

Comment: hi I've answered underneath the code you've posted, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want hand and masterhand to have two separate vectors with the same name? Maybe you should have a basichand that hols the vector + basic functionality. Then extend basichand with hand and masterhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added and simplified some of the code. But I will point you to some resources on polymorphism to get you started. I also remove the AbstractClass entirely since from an OOP perspective, you have objects that are Hands and another Master hand object.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//dummy class
struct Card{
    int x; 
};

class Hand{
 public: 
    Hand(){}
    std::vector<Card> handV;
    virtual ~Hand(){}        
    virtual void getCard(Card k) 
    {
        handV.push_back(k);
    }
    virtual void showHand() 
    {
        for(std::vector<Card>::const_iterator it = handV.begin(); 
            it != handV.end(); 
            it++) 
        std::cout << it->x << " ";
    }
};
class HandMaster: public Hand
{
    public:
    HandMaster(){} 
    //add additional methods
};

class HandOther: public Hand
{
    public:
    HandOther(){} 
    //add additional methods
};

class Deck
{
public:
    std::vector<Card> deck;
    Deck(){
        Card c;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 52; ++i){
            c.x = i; 
            deck.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    void passCard(Hand *x)
    {
        x->getCard(deck.back());
        deck.pop_back();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deck d;
    Hand* p = new Hand();
    HandMaster *m = new HandMaster();
    HandOther * o = new HandOther();
    for(int i =0; i < 5; ++i){
        d.passCard(p); 
        d.passCard(m); 
        d.passCard(o); 
    }
    std::cout << "\nHand:";
    p->showHand();
    std::cout << "\nHandMaster:";
    m->showHand();
    std::cout << "\nHandOther:";
    o->showHand();

    std::cout << "\n";
    delete o;
    delete p;
    delete m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly! I agree that that works and rewriting is also my temporary solution but imagine you had 10 different types of hand and all of them had the getCard function (and I have six more functions in Hand that work on the handV that I wanted the MasterHand to inherit)- the point is  to avoid rewriting them all for every XHand class so that they use their own handV- I'm not sure if I'm being clear? Let me know if not!

Comment: Ah I think I see. So MasterHand's get card will work just like Hands? You can acheive this by just having MasterHand Inherit hand and not override any of hands methods. Each derived hand class will contain the handV defined in the hand class.

Comment: What about you move the vector of Cards to the base class and implement the getCard as a non-virtual function, which will call a virtual function to select the card and add them to the vector of Cards. In the derived classes, you only have to implement the select function.

Comment: So my understanding would be that all "hands" would share the handV declared in Hand rather than have separate ones, that's what I found before when I was testing different options- by instantiating MasterHand as AbstractClass and then trying to write into the handV I would end up writing into handV associated with the instance of handV- but it might be my negligence so if you think it works I will check it out tomorrow when my brain starts working again ;)

Comment: That's one solution if you want to avoid rewriting a method that does the same task! Note that @HảiPhạmLê also posed an alternative method. Keep this question open if you want to see other alternatives. I kept out a lot of details, but consider looking into this link. It should help you. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/

Comment: Hi Hai Pham Le, but then is the virtual class still useful if you need to call the non-virtual from the main?

Comment: Sorry my comment was meant to say:So my understanding would be that all "hands" would share the handV declared in Hand rather than have separate ones, that's what I found before when I was testing different options- by instantiating MasterHand as AbstractClass and then trying to write into the handV I would end up writing into handV associated with the Hand instance of handV- but it might be my negligence so if you think it works I will check it out tomorrow when my brain starts working again ;)

Comment: If you have a class hand with a vector of cards. Will HandMaster need an additional vector of cards? If so, when you declare a second vector in HandMaster, the handmaster will now consist of 2 vectors, one inherited from Hand class and the other. To access the one in Hand you can use the scope resolution operator (Hand::cardV) .

Comment: hi so I would like Hand::handV and HandMaster::handV to be separate- my impression was- when testing- that both Hand and HandMaster were using Hand:handV but I might be wrong?

Comment: So if you create two seperate object Hand h; HandMaster m; and HandMaster inherits Hand::handV. Your program will contain 2 seperate vectors. Inheriting attributes does not mean you are inheriting the objects instantiated, but rather extending the definition of the class. I am unsure whether HandMaster will need an additional hand? Or, if all hand types have the exact same funcitonality you can create an enum attribute to distinguish between the types. This will eliminate all inheritance

Comment: @Natalia: Virtual means can be modified at the children, so I think it's perfectly fine here for the parent to define the flow and the children to implement it. unless you must have a pure virtual base class.

Comment: thanks guys; both solutions work, thanks for your time